# spelling corrector

Tags: words, spelling, sentence

My question is if there is some tool for spelling correction. I've seen bigrams analysis, Jaccard coefficient, and dictionaries based on training documents (python). Their results are very accurate (80-90%), but they can't correct sentences, for example "welcometo"-> "welcome to". 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try experimenting with Hunspell. It is default spell checker for Mozilla, MacOS. If you are using python try [pyhunspell](https://code.google.com/p/pyhunspell/)

Comment: Here is the updated link: http://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell. And for the correction your example works with pyhunspell. The suggest method gives me the following suggestions `['welcome to', 'welcome-to', 'welcome']`